# Embedding swf file as raw files in android

Tags: android, flash

hey can someone tell me how to embed a file like this 
http://circa-med.org/circa-med.swf

and play it in android. I m a beginner. So dont even know how to play video files. 
It will help if u are android specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using webview and run it without internet connection. Also note that swf fle needs flash player on phone. And since emulator does not support flash the code below will have a blank square.

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.GameWebView);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
gamePlay="<html><head><title></title></head>" +
    "<body>" +
    "<object codebase='http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0?' " +
    "width='320' height='240'>" +
    "<param name='movie' value='"+ Path +"'" +
    "<embed src='file:///android_asset/games/tokudu.swf' " +
    "pluginspage='http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/'" + 
    "type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='320' height='240'>" +
    "</embed>" +
    "</object>" +
    "</body></html>";
    webview.loadData(gamePlay, "text/html" ,"utf-8");
```

Comment: EDIT: gamePlay="<html><head><title></title></head>" +
"<body>" +
"<object codebase='http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0?' " +
 "width='320' height='240'>" +
"<param name='movie' value='"+ Path +"'" +
"<embed src='file:///android_asset/games/tokudu.swf' " +
"pluginspage='http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/'" + 
"type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='320' height='240'>" +
"</embed>" +
"</object>" +
"</body></html>";
webview.loadData(gamePlay, "text/html" ,"utf-8"); I am not able to add this snippet in the answer section so adding here.

Answer (score 0):

Just place the swf file in assets folder. Rest is nothing.
If the following code is not working. It means that the device you are using have some problem. As this code works on spice tab tested and not on AROMA. **

```
public class flashapp extends Activity 
{
    private WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

        String html = "<object width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_asset/flash_file.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///android_asset/flash_file.swf\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> </embed> </object>";
        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";

        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn't be too hard to put it on a web page. Use a free service like pastehtml to host the code.

```
<object width="320" height="240">
<param name="movie" value="http://circa-med.org/circa-med.swf">
<embed src="http://circa-med.org/circa-med.swf" width="320" height="240"></embed>
</object>
```

Here's a live example: http://pastehtml.com/view/1ct84ug.html

By the way, that example you listed takes a long time to load. That could be the problem, considering it's a mobile device.

Comment: Is that possible to embedd the swf file in the apk and make it work without any internet connexion?